# Incompatible conditional operand types double and double Java(16777232) when using instanceof

Tags: java, instanceof

I've been working on a personal Java project which essentially is mimicking a trading common backtesting spreadsheet. Everything has been fine up until the use of multiple `instanceof` operators in one line. I've had a look online and to no avail have found nothing relevant. I receive an incompatible conditional operand on the comparison of the `double` type and `int` however the string is fine. The editor I use is VSCode. Code is below

```
            while (newLogBool){
            Scanner newLog = new Scanner(System.in);
            String nLPair = newLog.nextLine();
            double nLStartingBalance = newLog.nextDouble();
            int nLRisk = newLog.nextInt();

            try { Thread.sleep(100); } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

            if ((nLPair instanceof String) && (nLStartingBalance instanceof double) && (nLRisk instanceof int)){
                Logger logger = new Logger(nLPair, nLStartingBalance, nLRisk);
                newLogBool = false;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Inccorect Type: Pair, Starting Balance or Risk. Please try again.");
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: You can only use `instanceof` with non-primitive types, meaning classes. `String` is a class while both `double` and `int` are primitives. There is no need for that check at all, remove it. `nLPair` can only be a `String` (not even a subclass since `String` is `final`), `nLStartingBalance` can only be a `double` and `nLRisk` can only be `int`.

Comment: This fixed it thank you! I just wanted to check if the inputs were valid datatypes.

Comment: Checking the data types is already done by `Scanner`'s methods. The call to `nextDouble()` will throw an Exception if the input is not a double. You cannot squeeze a non-double into a double, which makes checking irrelevant.

Comment: I did not know this. Thanks for the help, next time I'll read the documentation more thoroughly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `instanceof` operator can only be applied to reference types (or null).  `double` and `int` are primitive types, not reference types.

[Java Language Specification, 15.20.02](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2)

In your case, for example, an `int` is an instance of an `int`, and cannot be otherwise.  So there's no need to be able to ask that particular question.